# How to get rid of the ifcfg-Auto interface?

Tags: ethernet

I'm currently handling a RHEL 6.4 system's network interface problem, which is, the system seemed to configure network automatically but always fail. And My goal is simple, just want to configure address manually to establish connection, not DHCP.

And yes, I do know RHEL version 6.4 is too old. I don't want to use such museum piece either.

This host is cloned from an existing VM which network interfaces were "eth0","eth1" and "eth2" before, and the OS has desktop UI.

I plugged-in two new NIC ports instead of the old NICs to this host (and never touch them since then) therefore I believed that the new interface should be only the "eth3" and "eth4" (also because the system is always detecting eth3 and eth4 for me).

As shown in figures below:

[image]
[image]

I did configuring the eth3/eth4 via the UI and make the network online successfully, however, after a system reboot the network connection cleared my IP setting and start scanning network again.

So, my questions are here:

1. which is the safe way to remove the old network interfaces in the OS? I cannot mess up the network.
2. I want set address/settings for network manually and don't want the system to scan and create ifcfg-Auto devices, how can this be completed?